# MySQL update and join

Tags: mysql

[image: simple car table.]

[image: simple features table with color only.]

[image: I did a join with the code shown to get the resultant table.]

[image: I want to get the same resultant table, but with model replaced with 'speed demon' where ever color = red. I tried the code in the pic, but no go. Did some research, struck out. Any suggestions would be very appreciated!]

---

I'm having trouble with a MySQL join with update.

I have two simple tables as shown.

I did a join with the first code shown to get the resultant table.

I want to get the same resultant table, but with model replaced with 'speed demon' where ever color = red. I tried the code in the last pic, but no go. Did some research, struck out. Any suggestions would be very appreciated!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the source code/queries inside your question. Don't post them as images, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question. Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Comment: I have a disability right now and it takes me about an hour to do 5 mins of work. The best I can do presently is communicate with screen shots. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

With a join of the tables:

```
update car c inner join features f
on f.id = c.colorid and f.color = 'Red'
set c.model = 'speed demon';
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3o9ipSR2iQBZZem9GbZ3ZS/0).
Results:

```
| id  | model       | colorid |
| --- | ----------- | ------- |
| 1   | speed demon | 1       |
| 2   | Camaro      | 2       |
| 3   | speed demon | 1       |
| 4   | Torino      | 3       |
| 5   | speed demon | 1       |
| 6   | 208Z        | 3       |
```

Comment: Now I need to figure out how to display resultant table with just c.model and f.color columns.

Comment: Looks like line 5 from the far right Query SQL column in your demo link is where I need to fiddle about.

Comment: Thanks again for the great help!

Comment: @Coolhand if this solved your problem consider accepting the answer.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: @Coolhand Click on the checkmark at the left of my answer